# Raise event with custom EventArgs without blocking, without regard for the result

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

I am writing a little TCP application and I am trying to make an event that *won't* block the execution of the program.

Basically, a `TCPCOnnection` class raises an event, `ClientConnected` and passes the associated `Socket` to any event subscribers. I want the `TCPConnection` to go back to listening for a new connection *right away*. Also, I don't intend to do any error handling on this event in this class so I don't care much for a callback to check the result.

Here is the (simple) code:

```
    //Processes a new connection and immediately puts the listen socket back in a receiving state
    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientConnected?.Invoke(this, 
            new Event.ClientConnectedEventArgs(e.AcceptSocket));

        StartAccept();
    }

    #region Events
    //Fired when a client connects
    public event EventHandler<Event.ClientConnectedEventArgs> ClientConnected;

    #endregion
```

I know that if a subscriber to this event does some lengthy processing on each new connection, then clients will be waiting in line to connect.

`BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` seem to have a big emphasis on the *result* of the event's invocation, which as I said, I don't care for.

I was reading a few other questions and noticed some people recommended using a new *Task* but these answers were not the accepted, nor the best answers.

How can I accomplish this?

Am I a "bad programmer" for ignoring the result of the event invocation? (is it bad practice?)

Thank you!